# 'Module object has no attribute 'get' Python error Requests?

Tags: python, error-handling, python-requests

I just installed the Requests module by using `easy_install`
and I tried to run the demo code of this [tutorial](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request),

```
import requests
payload = {'username': 'xxxx', 'password': 'xxxxx'}
r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
```

but I get this error:

> AttributeError: `'module' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: change your file name , because python mainly checks for the packages with in the directory after that it will check in the python path.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are importing all names from the `requests` module into your local namespace, which means you do not need to prefix them anymore with the module name:

```
>>> from requests import *
>>> get
<function get at 0x107820b18>
```

If you were to import the module with an `import requests` statement instead, you added the module itself to your namespace and you do have to use the full name:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get
<function get at 0x102e46b18>
```

Note that the above examples is what I got from my tests in the interpreter. If you get different results, you are importing the wrong module; check if you have an extra `requests.py` file in your python package:

```
>>> import requests
>>> print requests.__file__
/private/tmp/requeststest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.pyc
```

You can also test for the name listing provided by the `requests` module:

```
>>> print dir(requests)
['ConnectionError', 'HTTPError', 'Request', 'RequestException', 'Response', 'Session', 'Timeout', 'TooManyRedirects', 'URLRequired', '__author__', '__build__', '__builtins__', '__copyright__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__license__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__title__', '__version__', '_oauth', 'api', 'auth', 'certs', 'codes', 'compat', 'cookies', 'defaults', 'delete', 'exceptions', 'get', 'head', 'hooks', 'models', 'options', 'packages', 'patch', 'post', 'put', 'request', 'safe_mode', 'session', 'sessions', 'status_codes', 'structures', 'utils']
```

Comment: Thanks,problem solved, i deleted the other Requests directory and it works

Comment: Yes duplicate existance of the file (requests.py) is the problem, I wrote a file named requests.py and here i imported "requests" module.So python engine look get method in the nearest one i.e. the current file name. Solution is renaming the file i am writing.

Answer (score 39):

This is the typical symptom of an unrelated `requests.py` (or `requests.pyc`) file sitting in your current directory, or somewhere else on the `PYTHONPATH`. If this is the case, remove or rename it, as it's shadowing the module you really want to import.

Comment: Similar to this, I accidentally ran `pip install requests` as root. When I ran python as a different user, I didn't get an import error. Rather I got this error. Had to change permissions in site-packages where pip had installed requests and all was good.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same error.

All I did was save it as `requests.py`

Then I saved it as some other name.
And problem solved.

Comment: mee too... tq bro

Answer (score 10):

As already stated, the most common problem is that you have a `requests.py` file somewhere in your `PYTHONPATH`.

But as the requests module internally uses other modules (e.g. from the standard python library), there might be problems with other filenames as well. For example I had the same problem when I named a script `http.py`. In that case the output of `print dir(requests)` is correct which makes tracking down the error a bit more difficult...

Comment: Thanks. I just got bitten writing some example code.  I never intended it to be imported, but in hindsight, json.py wasn't the most sensible filename to choose :/

Comment: Thanks... my issues was a file named http.py... Renamed it and I'm good.

Comment: Same with a file called json.py

Answer (score 4):

You have to variants of how to fix this.

```
import requests
```

or

```
r = get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
```

P.S. First one is preferable

Comment: @mojians Show me `print dir(requests)` pls.

Comment: ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'requests']

Comment: @mojians Something wrong with your `requests` package. Should be `['ConnectionError', 'HTTPError', 'Request', 'RequestException', 'Response', 'Session', 'Timeout', 'TooManyRedirects', 'URLRequired',  ..., 'api', 'auth', 'codes', 'compat', 'cookies', 'defaults', 'delete', 'exceptions', 'get', 'head', 'hooks', 'models', 'options', 'packages', 'patch', 'post', 'put', 'request', 'safe_mode', 'session', 'sessions', 'status_codes', 'structures', 'utils']`. Possible you have `requests.py` file in current directory.

Comment: Thanks,problem sovled, i deleted the other Requests directory,and it works

Answer (score 4):

I made a mistake of the test file's name was requests.py.
So, when i import requests.py, it's not what I want to import.
Then, I renamed the test file's name. It works!!!

Answer (score 3):

Please check if there is a python file named **requests.py** in your parent folder. In that case, it is the wrong package which is getting imported.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you name your file as requests.py. so please change the name of the file to something else as python do not differentiate between the module file and your code file.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an user error if you're working with a framework like Django that has request objects as well.

I constantly get confused by Django's:

```
request.POST
```

and `request`'s:

```
request.post
```

That was my problem, anyway. Bracing for down votes.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the filename solved my solution.

Previous name was: `random.py`

and Changed name is: `hello.py`

Answer (score 0):

I happened the same issue on Mac and Ubuntu. I want to test the requests command. I used the **requests/** folder name and the **requests.py** filename on Mac. 
But Python shows the "ImportError: cannot import name get" message.
Therefore, I have renamed the requests/ folder and the requests.py file to test-requests/ and test-requests.py. It still got the message. 
I checked the folder as below:

```
__pycache__     requests.pyc        test-1.py       test-requests.py
```

I saw that the folder has the requests.pyc file. So I deleted the requests.pyc file in the folder. Then, I executed the below test script. it's working now.

```
$ python test-requests.py 
200

#! /usr/bin/env python
# the content of test-requests.py
import requests
from requests import get
r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
print (r.status_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's easier to delete previous files or directories that are problematic.
If you are using mac use `rm` in the terminal.

[image: rm example]

Here's a link for more info: https://www.macworld.com/article/2082021/master-the-command-line-deleting-files-and-folders.html

Comment: the picture is the link but when I removed the previous file, I was able to successfully run my requests and bs4