# python - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-requests, attributeerror

I'm trying this simple code:

```
import requests
print requests.__file__
r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
```

It works flawlessly on the command line when I type the lines one by one, but not whenen when I execute it as a script or in Sublime Text 2. Here's the stack trace:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.pyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bruce\Desktop\http.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 15, in <module>
    from http.client import HTTPConnection, HTTPException
  File "C:\Users\Bruce\Desktop\http.py", line 3, in <module>
    r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get'
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

Answers on ['Module object has no attribute 'get' Python error Requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258816/module-object-has-no-attribute-get-python-error-requests) didn't help much.

Could this be some error in my ST2 Python build system? I tried removing all `requests` modules in case there were multiples of them by using `pip` and reinstalled them.

Comment: Do you've a `requests.py` file in the `Desktop` folder?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary No!

Comment: Could you double check and do `print requests.__file__` please...

Comment: @Bruce okay - and then a `print dir(requests)`?

Comment: @JonClements If the script has just one line `print dir(requests)` after `import requests`, I'm getting two arrays as output - one having all attributes with underscores, and the other which has the `get` method. I guess the script is running twice? http://pastebin.com/WcBa7Qr5

Comment: Ummm - not sure - can't think of any other ideas on how to diagnose this at the moment - sorry!

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - thanks for this question. I was chasing my tail until I saw your comment.  To add clarity, if the script is named `requests.py` and you `import requests`, you'll get a conflict. Rename the script _and_ delete the file `requests.pyc` if you have one in the same location.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit** After reading the stacktrace again, you can see that `urllib3` tries to import something from the `http` module. Your file is called `http.py` and is thus imported instead of the expected one.

The actual error happens because of the circular nature of the import. Since `requests` hasn't finished importing completely yet. The `get` function in `requests` isn't defined yet when the `http` import reaches `import requests` again.

**Note**: You will also want to always guard your entry point with the `if __name__ == '__main__'` construct. This will often avoid nasty errors for unsuspecting future developers (including yourself).

Comment: @Bruce ah sorry, I was close though. I just noticed that `urllib3` does an `from http.client import HTTPConnection, HTTPException`. It seems your `http.py` file is shadowing that instead? Try renaming it.

Comment: By the way, my point still stands. Always guard your entry point!

Comment: My error was `'module' object has no attribute 'post'` and my filename was `email.py`. Renaming the file fixed it! Thanks!