# Why is this Python code running twice?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I have a Python script with just these 2 lines:

```
import requests
print len(dir(requests))
```

It prints:

```
12
48
```

When I print the actual list `dir(requests)`, I get this:

```
['__author__', '__build__', '__builtins__', '__copyright__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__license__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__title__', '__version__']
['ConnectionError', 'HTTPError', 'NullHandler', 'PreparedRequest', 'Request', 'RequestException', 'Response', 'Session', 'Timeout', 'TooManyRedirects', 'URLRequired', '__author__', '__build__', '__builtins__', '__copyright__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__license__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__title__', '__version__', 'adapters', 'api', 'auth', 'certs', 'codes', 'compat', 'cookies', 'delete', 'exceptions', 'get', 'head', 'hooks', 'logging', 'models', 'options', 'packages', 'patch', 'post', 'put', 'request', 'session', 'sessions', 'status_codes', 'structures', 'utils']
```

I'm guessing there are multiple `requests` modules or something like that. Please help.

Comment: What "actual arrays" are these? When do you print them? More information, please.

Comment: Oops. The *list* returned by `dir(requests)`. Edited

Comment: But you're only doing that once. Under what circumstances do you get each?

Comment: @kindall The script has just these 2 lines

Comment: It'll probably be worth mentioning in terms of context that this question is a spin-off from attempts to [sort this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528149/python-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute)

Comment: @JonClements Yes it is! And I hope that's fine to do?

Comment: @Bruce indeed it is - so [edit] this to include that - and it'll give context to people looking at this, and might even end up solving your other one at the same time

Comment: Is the script named `requests.py` by any chance?

Comment: @kindall `http.py` ! Solved.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You gave your script a name of a standard module or something else that is imported by the `requests` package. You created a circular import.

```
yourscript -> import requests -> [0 or more other modules] -> import yourscript -> import requests again
```

Because `requests` didn't *complete* importing the first time you get to see these differences in the list of supported objects.

Don't do that. Rename your script to something else and it'll all work.

Comment: Jesus. It was `http.py`.

Comment: This answer saved my life. Thank you! I'm executing multiple scripts in one go and discovered that I created a circular import that caused the same issue. Lesson learned!

Answer (score 1):

First one is your own module
Second is module for dealing with HTTP requests.
Rename ur own module