# module 'requests' has no attribute 'files'

Tags: flask, python-requests

Running the script gives below error :

```
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'files'
```

Code is as follows :

```
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/test/', methods=['POST'])
def test(): 
    filesReceived = requests.files['file']
```

Comment: Hello! Does your question answer this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258816/module-object-has-no-attribute-get-python-error-requests/12259876

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your code, you are trying to get the file received by the request, right?

If that's what you want, you are using the wrong import.

[Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) is an http library for python.

If you want the file sent in the request, you need to use [**request from flask**](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=request#flask.request).

So your code will be something like:

```
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/test/', methods=['POST'])
def test(): 
    filesReceived = request.files['file']
```