# How to save JSON response from browser into python variable or file

Tags: python

I am a newbie to python and api queries. However, I am learning python automation in the process.
Request your kind help here.

I have a SonarQube API call through which I fetch some metrics or values as a JSON response on my browser. I read that curl or through requests module in python, we would be able to download the response into a variable or file. How much ever I try, I am not able to do through a program. Right now, I am hard coding it in a variable and proceeded with my next steps. Can someone help me here.

Query I use:

```
https://sonar.com:9000/sonar/api/measures/component?component=abcdef&branch=test&metricKeys=ncloc
```

I get JSON response like this on the browser:

```
  "component": {
    "id": "AXK4GYajYOT4RM44Ji",
    "key": "abcdef",
    "name": "test",
    "qualifier": "TRK",
    "measures": [
      {
        "metric": "ncloc",
        "value": "100000"
      }
    ],
    "branch": "test"
  }
}
```

My intention is to store all of this in a python variable.

Comment: Take a look at the [requests package](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content).

Comment: Note: You are not getting a response "from browser". You are getting it from an HTTP Server

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `requests` package you can store the response in the `data` variable as follows:

```
import requests

params = {'component': 'abcdef', 'branch': 'test', 'metricKeys': 'ncloc'}
r = requests.get('https://sonar.com:9000/sonar/api/measures/component', params=params)
data = r.json()

print(data)
```

if you then want to store it as a `JSON` file:

```
import json
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have tried this solution. The error I see is: AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'      Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have a custom file called `requests.py` already (which would conflict with the package)? see here also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258816/module-object-has-no-attribute-get-python-error-requests

Comment: No. I dont have any requests.py file in my project directory. I have a JSON reponse like this: '''{
  "component": {
    "id": "AXK4GYajYOT4RM44Ji",
    "key": "abcdef",
    "name": "test",
    "qualifier": "TRK",
    "measures": [
      {
        "metric": "ncloc",
        "value": "134439"
      }
    ],
    "branch": "test"
  }
}'''  I have requests module installed.
requests   2.24.0        Error is AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'

Comment: I tested it and it works in a clean environment. Make sure you do not have any folders or files in your `PYTHONPATH` that are named `requests`.